# problem sending an email with an attachment programmatically

Tags: android

i`m trying to send an email using native email client on android
phone.

I have tried following ways to add an attachment to the mail...

method--1

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/abc.jpg"));
```

method 2

Sending the image as body content---

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<HTML><BODY><b><IMG**SRC=
\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + <imagepath> + "\"**alt = \"**pleaseview this
image\"/></b></BODY></HTML>");
```

i can successfully attach the image manually but when i tried to
attach and send it programmatically the mail was sent without
attachement.

Please let me know if there is a way to send an attachment
programmatically by using email client

Comment: check this : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/207/how-to-send-email-programmatically-in-android/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are not putting right the file path.

The following works for me:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setType("image/jpg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Pictures/
image.jpg"));
startActivity(i);
```

Note that file path has 3 "/", the first two for the "file://" header, the other because sdcard dir is inside the root of the filesystem, which is "/" in linux.

Comment: this does not solve the problem with embedding the image inside the html email, does it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `Uri` you are using is incorrect. I tried `file:///mnt/sdcard/` and worked quite fine.