# Android Send Intent attaching photo from sdcard as 0 length file

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I know a variant of this question was asked before 
[trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587917/trying-to-attach-a-file-from-sd-card-to-email/1279574#1279574)
But the solution offered, i.e. a reboot doesn't seem to do it for me.  I have seen a good number of group postings which support this being a problem.  I can only assume the OP for the linked to question made some other changes, possibly to the manifest which allowed his code to work.

The behaviour I am seeing is the Email intent handling the attachment of the jpeg from the sdcard but dealing with it as a 0 length file which is discarded when sent.  I have tried setType as jpeg/image and image/jpeg as I have seen it expressed both ways.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("jpeg/image");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "me@gmail.com");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, R.string.email_subjectStart + 
            mWhatYouSpotted.getSelectedItem().toString() +
            R.string.email_subjectEnd);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/"+ sPhotoFileName));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sEmailBody);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

Here is the adb logcat I got when I last tested:

> V/DumbDumpersMain( 3972): sPhotoUri=file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg I/ActivityManager( 56): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.CHOOSER comp={android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} (has extras) } I/ActivityManager( 56): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.SEND type=jpeg/image flags=0x3000000 comp={com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail} (has extras) } I/ActivityManager( 56): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.SEND type=jpeg/image flags=0x2800000 comp={com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivity} (has extras) } D/gmail-ls( 120): MailProvider.query: content://gmail-ls/labels/me@gmail.com(null, null) D/Gmail ( 2507): URI FOUND:file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg

I have been banging my head against this one for over a week now and still cannot determine what is wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Should have done more searching here before posting; [problem sending an email with an attachment programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247983/problem-sending-an-email-with-an-attachment-programmatically) solved it for me. I only have `file://sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg`, which annoyingly still looks like I have successfully attached the image. You need an extra `/` to make it work:

```
file:///sdcard/DumbDumpers/DumbDumper.jpg
       ^
```

Answer (score 4):

Your intent type is wrong. It should be

```
sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
```